# SQL: Count and subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

Again with count and sql

on sqlite, I have the tables

- papers: paper_id, doi, year
- writtenby: paper_id, author_id, inst_id
- authors: author_id, name, firstname
- inst: inst_id, name, see_id

inst is a table of Institutions: Universities and so on. 
Each line in writtenby gives a paper, an author, an institution this author was attached at that time. 
There can be more then one institution and the couple paper_id, author_id is repeated for each institution. 
For a given author, I want a list and of papers.doi, papers.year  and the count of cohautors he has written a paper with. 
I tried

```
 SELECT  papers.doi, papers.year, count(*) as c
 FROM authors 
 INNER JOIN writtenby ON authors.author_id =  writtenby.author_id
 INNER JOIN writtenby AS writtenby_1 ON writtenby.paper_id =  
 writtenby_1.paper_id
 INNER JOIN papers on  writtenby_1.paper_id = papers.paper_id 
 WHERE authors.name ='Beck' AND authors.firstname= 'H P' 
 GROUP BY papers.doi, papers.year
 ORDER BY c DESC
```

The problem I'm having could be that if the author I'm searching with appears twice for a given paper (because of two institutions)
the count is doubled. For a given paper the expected result of 2890, is given by the number of rows of

```
SELECT DISTINCT author_id
FROM writtenby 
WHERE paper_id = 4593
```

(with my data: 2890 rows)
Without distinct, I would have 3023 rows, and the first query above gives 6046 for count. I tried to use DISTINCT in the Count clause above but that still does not work.

Can I use count with a subquery ? Thanks for any help...

Sample Data:

```
-- Make the tables

CREATE TABLE 'authors' (name collate nocase, firstname collate nocase, see_id integer, 'author_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL );
CREATE TABLE 'inst' ('name' TEXT NOT NULL, 'country' TEXT NOT NULL , 'see_id' INTEGER, 'inst_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL );
CREATE TABLE 'papers' ('doi' TEXT NOT NULL,'year' TEXT NOT NULL, 'paper_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL );
CREATE TABLE 'writtenby' ('paper_id' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'author_id' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'inst_id' INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ('paper_id', 'author_id', 'inst_id'));

-- Insert the data 

-- authors : 5 names, one with 2 variants

INSERT INTO 'authors' (name, firstname, see_id, author_id) VALUES ('Doe', 'J', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO 'authors' (name, firstname, see_id, author_id) VALUES ('Klein', 'K', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO 'authors' (name, firstname, see_id, author_id) VALUES ('Lang', 'F', 3, 3);
INSERT INTO 'authors' (name, firstname, see_id, author_id) VALUES ('Rue', 'A De La', 6, 4);
INSERT INTO 'authors' (name, firstname, see_id, author_id) VALUES ('La Rue', 'A De', 6, 5);
INSERT INTO 'authors' (name, firstname, see_id, author_id) VALUES ('De La Rue', 'A', 6, 6);
INSERT INTO 'authors' (name, firstname, see_id, author_id) VALUES ('Smith', 'S', 7, 7);

-- inst 4 name, 2 variants

INSERT INTO 'inst' (name, country, see_id, inst_id) VALUES ('Universite de Paris', 'France', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO 'inst' (name, country, see_id, inst_id) VALUES ('Paris University', 'France', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO 'inst' (name, country, see_id, inst_id) VALUES ('Universite de Lyon', 'France', 3, 3);
INSERT INTO 'inst' (name, country, see_id, inst_id) VALUES ('Univ Freiburg', 'Germany', 4, 4);
INSERT INTO 'inst' (name, country, see_id, inst_id) VALUES ('EPFZ', 'Switzerland', 5, 5);
INSERT INTO 'inst' (name, country, see_id, inst_id) VALUES ('Eidg Techn Hochschule', 'Switzerland', 5, 6);

-- papers: 3 papers

INSERT INTO 'papers' (doi, year, paper_id) VALUES ('doi1', '2017', 1);
INSERT INTO 'papers' (doi, year, paper_id) VALUES ('doi2', '2018', 2);
INSERT INTO 'papers' (doi, year, paper_id) VALUES ('doi3', '2018', 3);

-- paper 1: 4 authors

INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (1, 6, 1);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (1, 6, 3);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (1, 1, 5);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (1, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (1, 7, 1);

-- paper 2: 3 authors

INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (2, 6, 1);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (2, 6, 3);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (2, 1, 5);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (2, 2, 5);

-- paper 3: 3 authors

INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (3, 6, 1);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (3, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (3, 6, 3);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (3, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (3, 3, 4);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (3, 3, 5);
INSERT INTO 'writtenby' (paper_id, author_id,  inst_id) VALUES (3, 3, 1);
```

Check the queries:

```
 SELECT  papers.doi, papers.year, count(*) as c
 FROM authors 
 INNER JOIN writtenby ON authors.author_id =  writtenby.author_id
 INNER JOIN writtenby AS writtenby_1 ON writtenby.paper_id =  
 writtenby_1.paper_id
 INNER JOIN papers on  writtenby_1.paper_id = papers.paper_id 
 WHERE authors.name ='De La Rue' AND authors.firstname= 'A' 
 GROUP BY papers.doi, papers.year
 ORDER BY c DESC


SELECT p.doi, p.year, COUNT(w2.author_id) AS cnt
FROM authors a
INNER JOIN writtenby w1
    ON a.author_id =  w1.author_id
INNER JOIN writtenby w2
    ON w1.paper_id = w2.paper_id AND w1.author_id <> w2.author_id
INNER JOIN papers p
    ON w2.paper_id = p.paper_id 
WHERE
    a.name = 'De La Rue' AND a.firstname = 'A'
GROUP BY
    p.doi, p.year
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC;
```

Both queries gives wrong results
First one:

```
doi3|2018|14
doi1|2017|10
doi2|2018|8
```

Second query

```
doi3|2018|10
doi1|2017|6
doi2|2018|4
```

François

Answer (score 1):

One counting problem I see is happening is in your self-join of the `writtenby` table.  There, you are not checking that the matching row has a *different* `author_id`.  If the `author_id` be the same, then you should not be counting it.  Also, what you should be counting for the number of shared authors is the second `writtenby` table.  This way, should a given author not have any coauthors, the count would show up as zero.

```
SELECT p.doi, p.year, COUNT(w2.author_id) AS cnt
FROM authors a
INNER JOIN writtenby w1
    ON a.author_id =  w1.author_id
INNER JOIN writtenby w2
    ON w1.paper_id = w2.paper_id AND w1.author_id <> w2.author_id
INNER JOIN papers p
    ON w2.paper_id = p.paper_id 
WHERE
    a.name = 'Beck' AND a.firstname = 'H P'
GROUP BY
    p.doi, p.year
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ! But it still gives much to high count  
 10.1140/epjc/s10052-018-6219-9 2018 6042
10.1103/PhysRevD.98.112010 2018 5838
10.1007/JHEP05(2018)195 2018 5790<\b>Where the number of authors is around 3'000

Comment: Then at this point you need to make your question/problem reproducible.  The best way to do this is by adding sample data, and both the current and expected output.  I see nothing wrong other than what my answer has already mentioned.

Comment: Your link appears to be broken, but in any case, please _don't_ paste data links in your question.  Just edit your question and make it complete by showing the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Tim Biegeleisen and the sample data, I found that what was missing is the clause DISTINCT in the count

```
SELECT p.doi, p.year, COUNT(DISTINCT w2.author_id) AS cnt
FROM authors a
INNER JOIN writtenby w1
ON a.author_id =  w1.author_id
INNER JOIN writtenby w2
ON w1.paper_id = w2.paper_id 
INNER JOIN papers p
ON w2.paper_id = p.paper_id 
WHERE
a.name = 'De La Rue' AND a.firstname = 'A'
GROUP BY
p.doi, p.year
ORDER BY
cnt DESC;
```

give the total number of authors.

```
doi1    2017    4
doi2    2018    3
doi3    2018    3
```

Withe the clause `w1.author_id <> w2.author_id`, the count is reduced by one.

F.