# SQL count once again

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I'm using the sample data described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111382/sql-count-and-subquery)

I would like to have a list of institutions with the counting of their occurrence across all papers for a given author.

This query gives a list which is correct

```
SELECT  DISTINCT p.name || ", " || p.country as col1,  w2.paper_id,   w2.inst_id
FROM (
    authors a
    INNER JOIN writtenby w1 
   ON a.author_id = w1.author_id 
    INNER JOIN writtenby w2 
   ON w1.paper_id = w2.paper_id 
     INNER JOIN inst p 
   ON  w2.inst_id = p.inst_id 

) 
WHERE (a.name) = "De La Rue"  AND (a.firstname) = "A"
```

I count three occurrences of inst_id = 5 for example.

I'm unable to translate this count with SQL.

I tried this

```
SELECT  DISTINCT p.name || ", " || p.country as col1,  count(w2.paper_id)
FROM (
    authors a
    INNER JOIN writtenby w1 
   ON a.author_id = w1.author_id 
    INNER JOIN writtenby w2 
   ON w1.paper_id = w2.paper_id 
     INNER JOIN inst p 
   ON  w2.inst_id = p.inst_id 

) 
WHERE (a.name) = "De La Rue"  AND (a.firstname) = "A"
GROUP BY  w2.inst_id
```

Which returns:

```
col1    count(w2.paper_id)
Universite de Paris, France 12
Universite de Lyon, France  6
Univ Freiburg, Germany  6
EPFZ, Switzerland   8
```

And that seems completely wrong...

Thanks for any correction !

François

Answer (score 0):

Try using `COUNT(DISTINCT w2.paper_id)` rather than `COUNT(w2.paper_id)`.

Comment: @fraz The best way to thank people is explained here this...https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Consider accepting answers for your other questions so far (none of which have accepted answers).